# How to pass query parameters into Kusto http_request

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

How can i pass query parameters (in this case for wp.1) into Kusto http_request?
I want to write a Kusto function which can return some results for gps coordinates.
Is this possible or must the uri be static? Which other solution is possible?

```
let GpsLat = '47.2429490282';
let GpsLong = '9.3393486426';
let uri = @'http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes?wp.0=45.980537,7.641618&wp.1={GpsLat},{GpsLong}&key=THE_KEY';
evaluate http_request(uri)
```

Comment: At this point only hard-coded values are possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then I will create an Azure Function that updates the information from the API into the kusto table